# Apple iTunes Connect: issues in adding Test Flight user

Tags: ipad, app-store-connect, itunes, testflight

Since the latest upgrade of iTunes connect, I'm having issues to add Test Flight users as internal tester. when I add one users, all other users are being removed.

Here some details:

- I'm logged in with a user that has Admin role
- Users appear correctly in the Users and Roles section because have accepted the first invitation email
- Users have different roles: Developer, Marketer, Admin. The issue seems to not be related to their role
- I can see users in the My Apps -> Test Flight -> Internal Testing page in the Internal Testers column

The issue is: when I add one or more users to the Internal Testing page, all the existing users are being automatically removed.

I'm overcoming this issue by:

- first removing all internal testers from the list
- then by adding back all users and the new ones.

The side-effect of this approach is that invitation emails are sent to all users everytime, causing useless confusion.

Do you know if this is a known bug of iTunes connect or if there is something I should check?

Thanks
Luca

Comment: May be a bit stupid but did you try in Safari?

Comment: I tried with Chrome on Windows and Safari on Mac: same issue.